# Can the callback parameter in FirebaseAuthClient take a context parameter?

Tags: firebase

I see that the `on` method of a Firebase ref can take a `context` parameter that is `this` within the context of the callback. This is incredibly useful. I am wondering -- and hoping -- that the callback function that is provided to `FirebaseAuthClient` can also take a callback, but my intense scrutiny of the Examples, Getting Started and SDK documentation reveal no mention of it. I attempted to scour the minified `firebase-auth-client.js` but stopped with my sanity still intact.

A related question: FirebaseAuthClient does not seem to be included in the JavaScript SDK area. Is it anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Engineer at Firebase]

The Firebase Simple Login constructor now accepts a context argument as its third argument. For example, to have your Simple Login callback invoked with `myContextObj` as its context:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com');
var simpleLogin = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(ref, function(error, user) { ... }, myContextObj);
```

Comment: It would be very deisrable. I am finding that I am jumping through some rather extraordinary JavaScript hoops in order to keep my application from having the authentication logic tightly-coupled to the UI. Since I am planning on making my application available on several different platforms, this is not a trivial consideration.

Comment: Also, is there official documentation anywhere for the FirebaseAuthClient that I just haven't been able to track down?

Comment: The documentation for Firebase Simple Login is available at https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html, which I'm sure you've seen. It cover all publicly-exposed features in the auth. client, but at some point we might break this out into full-API reference format like we have for the JS SDK and Security. Please let me know what other feedback you have as it comes up!